# DATABRICKS SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult - CAN'T DISPLAY DATAFRAME

Tags: pyspark

I need some help please.

I run this command: display(df), but when I try to download the dataframe I obtain the following error:

SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read job commit marker: FileStatus{path=dbfs:/databricks-results/1390434353332427/_committed_8779047008713225709; isDirectory=false; length=114; replication=1; blocksize=67108864; modification_time=1583486899000; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rwx-wx-wx; isSymlink=false}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you help to understand, what exactly you are trying by share some sample code snippet?

Comment: pivot = df.groupBy("ClaimCode_FailureCode", "FailureDate", "class").pivot("dtc_code").sum("frequenza") ;
display(pivot)